# Write columns as rows (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table:

| campaign_id | media | installs | content_view | date | unique_purchase |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7564 | google | 613 | 45 | 2021-09-01 | 1 |
| 7564 | facebook | 21 | 33 | 2021-09-02 | 2 |
| 3451 | google | 83 | 12 | 2021-09-01 | 0 |

I want to create view:

- write `installs` column values as `metric_key=installs`, `metric_name=installs`, `metric_value=...`
- write `content_view` and `unique_purchase` as `metric_key=event`, `metric_name=column_name`, `metric_value=...`

| id | media_source | metric_key | metric_name | metric_value | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7564 | google | installs | installs | 613 | 2021-09-01 |
| 7564 | facebook | installs | installs | 21 | 2021-09-02 |
| 3451 | google | installs | installs | 83 | 2021-09-01 |
| 7564 | google | event | unique_purchase | 1 | 2021-09-01 |
| 7564 | facebook | event | unique_purchase | 2 | 2021-09-02 |
| 3451 | google | event | unique_purchase | 0 | 2021-09-01 |
| 7564 | google | event | content_view | 45 | 2021-09-01 |
| 7564 | facebook | event | content_view | 33 | 2021-09-02 |
| 3451 | google | event | content_view | 12 | 2021-09-01 |

Also it should be groupped by `campaign_id`, `media`, `date`.

How to achieve it with Postgres? I dont understand `crosstab` clearly. Thanks!

Comment: As for crosstab, have you read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `lateral join`:

```
select t.id, t.media_source, v.*, t.date
from t cross join lateral
     (values ('installs', t.installs, 'installs'),
             ('event', t.unique_purchase, 'unique_purchase'),
             ('event', t.content_view, 'content_view')
     ) v(metric_key, metric_name, metric_value);
```

Comment: How much does it affect performance if I have not 3 such columns (installs, content_view and unique_purchase), but 20?

Comment: @hsadik . . . With three columns, this should be faster than `union all`.  With 20 columns, much, much faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can select specific subset of data and stack them on top of each other. One can assign column names directly in the `select` queries instead of using a `CTE`. It's just a personal preference.

```
create view my_metric_view as

with cte (id, media_source, metric_key, metric_name, metric_value, date) as

(select campaign_id,
        media,
        'installs',
        'installs',
        installs,
        date
 from t
 where metric_name='installs'

 union all

 select campaign_id,
        media,
        'event',
        'unique_purchase',
        unique_purchase,
        date
 from t
 where metric_name='unique_purchase'

 union all

 select campaign_id,
        media,
        'event',
        'content_view',
        content_view,
        date
 from t
 where metric_name='content_view')

select * 
from cte;
```